# How to force pooling + upsample to result in same size?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Suppose I have an input image of unknown size, say `(batch_size, None, None, 64)`.  I would like to run it through a pooling layer and then later upsample it back to the same size in order to concatenate with the original:

```
P = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(4, padding='same')(inp)
```

then later:

```
U = keras.layers.UpSampling2D(4)(P)
```

But if the input size is not divisible by 4, `U` may be bigger than `P` in one or both dimensions (I *think* the `padding='same'` prevents it from being smaller). What syntax can I use to cut `U` back down to the size of `P`?

Comment: the easy solution is to resize the images to have a dimension that is a power of 2, worst solutions would be to create a lambda layer to add a padding or to cut the border pixels (depending on the size)

Comment: If I wanted to pad or truncate, is it allowable to create a network that references the size of the input?  I'm not clear on whether or how this can be done.